# Why my program didn't execute the upper method in classes

Tags: python, oop

```
class Test:
    alive = True
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def calling(self):
        return f'hello!! {self.name}. You are {self.age}. Are you alive {self.alive}'
    
class Test_child(Test):
    pass
test1 = Test('Paul',19)

child1 = Test_child('John',27)

child1.calling()

child1.name = 'Adam'

child1.calling()
```

why my program executes only the last calling method from class. why not both of it ?

Comment: What evidence do you have for this claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that only the last method has been called. I think that there are print statements missing. For example :

```
child1.calling()
```

into

```
print(child1.calling())
```

I think that u have this prob, since you execute your code in jupyter notebook or google collab, isnt it?

Comment: yes, I was using Jupyter notebook and just exploring classes and oops